# How to use enum with associated value(s) in ink smart contract

Tags: ink, rust

I have an ink smart contract message that takes an enum as argument. The code is shown below;

```
#[derive(Encode, Decode)]
#[cfg_attr(
    feature = "std",
    derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, scale_info::TypeInfo, StorageLayout,)
)]
pub enum EncodableFunctions {
    SetAssets(Vec<ContentIdentifier>),
    ActivateVoting(u128),
}

 #[ink(message)]
    pub fn encode_function_name_and_input(
        &self,
        args: EncodableFunctions,
    ) -> ([u8; 4], Vec<u8>) {
        match args {
            EncodableFunctions::SetAssets => {
                let encoded_name = ink::selector_bytes!("set_default_assets");
                let inputs = ArgumentList::empty().push_arg(&args);
                let encoded_inputs = inputs.encode();
                (encoded_name, encoded_inputs)
            }
            EncodableFunctions::ActivateVoting => {
                let encoded_name = ink::selector_bytes!("activate_voting");
                let inputs = ArgumentList::empty().push_arg(&args);
                let encoded_inputs = inputs.encode();
                (encoded_name, encoded_inputs)
            }
        }
    }
```

The contract builds successfully and I'm able to deploy to Substrate COntracts UI but when I try to interact with the function, I get a blank screen like the image below

[image: screenshot]

There's no such error if I replace the enum with no associated values, like enum below. Any way I can make the function work?

```
 #[derive(Encode, Decode)]
#[cfg_attr(
    feature = "std",
    derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, scale_info::TypeInfo, StorageLayout,)
)]
pub enum EncodableFunctions {
    SetAssets,
    ActivateVoting,
}
```